# Append strings to class variable in c++

Tags: c++, string, class, oop, append

I am just beginning with c++ and I need help. I need to append strings using the append() function in c++ and I am facing some problems. Here is my code.

```
class Foo
{
  char* str1;
  Foo()
  {
    Foo::str1=0;
  }
  void appendFoo(Foo foo1)
  {
    foo1.str1.append("Hello");
  }
}
```

I know the above code is wrong. How can I append string "Hello" through an object of class foo. I want the object foo1 to have str1 value as hello and if i call this function again, it should be appended. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `Foo::str1` as a `std::string`. Also, the parameter of `Foo::appendFoo()` should be of type `Foo&` so `foo1` in the function would not be a temporary copy.

```
#include <string>
class Foo
{
  std::string str1;
  Foo()
  {
    str1 = "";
  }
  void appendFoo(Foo &foo1)
  {
    foo1.str1.append("Hello");
  }
}
```

However, a better design could be making `Foo::appendFoo()` to append to string on the object itself. That is,

```
 void appendFoo()
 {
   str1.append("Hello");
 }

 // Calling example
 Foo bar;
 bar.appendFoo();
 // Now bar.str1 == "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on the type of data member str1. If its type would be std::string then there is no problem

```
class Foo
{
private:
  std::string str1;
public:
  Foo() = default;
  void appendFoo()
  {
    str1.append( "Hello" );
  }
};
```

If data member str1 shall have type char * as in your original code then the solution is more compound.

```
class Foo
{
private:
  char  *str1;
public:
  Foo() : str1( nullptr ) {}
  ~Foo() { delete []str1; }
  void appendFoo()
  {
    const char hello[] = "Hello";  
    char *tmp = new char[ std::strlen( str1 ) + sizeof( hello ) ]; 
    std::strcpy( tmp, str1 );
    std::strcat( tmp, hello );
    delete []str1;
    str1 = tmp;
  }
};
```

Also you need to define properly a copy constructtor and the copy assignment operator for this class.